# checkbox event binding with button in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm using angular. I have an input `type"checkbox"` and a button next to it. When clicking the button a method is called, `abc()`. I have to check whether checkbox is checked or not on the click of button.

**app.component.html**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbx">
<button (click)="abc();" class="btn btn-success">Search </button>
```

**app.component.ts**-

```
abc(){}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well a simple solution to your problem is to use simple two way binding manually

```
<input type="checkbox" [checked]="isChecked" (change)="isChecked = $event.target.checked" id="chckbx" style="width:30px;height:30px;"  >
<button (click)="abc();" class="btn btn-success" style="height: 30px;padding: 0px 30px">Search </button>

    //in your component use this code
    isChecked = false;

    abc() {
        if (!this.isChecked) {
            console.log('Checkbox cannot be unchecked...');
        }
    }
```

> It will solve the problem. However I do recommend to learn two way
>   data-binding `[(ngModel)]` approach. But you have to import some
>   modules properly to use `ngModel`.

Answer (score 4):

You can pass the reference of the checkbox in the `click` method. You need to use the `#var` template notation:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbx" #chkbox>
<button (click)="abc(chkbox)" class="btn btn-success">Search</button>


abc(checkbox: HTMLInputElement) {

    console.log(checkbox.checked);  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="checkbox" 
    [ngModel]="value"
    (ngModelChange)="changeValue()" 
    id="chckbx">
<button (click)="abc();" class="btn btn-success">Search </button>


changeValue() : void {
    this.value = !this.value;
  }

abc() : void {
  console.log(this.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bind the `checkbox` value with `ngModel`. Then use it in the `abc()` function.

html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chckbx" style="width:30px;height:30px;" [(ngModel)]="checked" >

<p>
 <button (click)="abc();" class="btn btn-success">Search </button>
</p>
```

app.component.ts:

```
checked: boolean = true;

abc(){
    alert(this.checked);
  }
```

[demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/YefrnQ25wlqnn8JvxEMm?p=preview)